# JBoss AS6 app specific logging

Tags: java, logging, jboss, jboss6.x

I'm currently **migrating** old web apps **from JBoss As 4.2.2 to 6.0.0 (AS6)**. In AS6 we have a proprietary format for logging applications through a file named `jboss-logging.xml`.

After read some stuff (http://community.jboss.org/wiki/SeparatingApplicationLogs) reach the conclusion that *"(...)starting with JBoss AS 6.0.0.M2 the ability to log to separate log files, per application, will be implemented in a different way"* and also that the documentation *"(...) will be updated with more details, once the implementation is ready"*.

However I was able to create the specific application log files in my `server/log` dir, it was done using the main `joboss-logging.xml` file in the `server/deploy` dir. This is not compatible with the modularity my applications demand.

So here the problem when I create a `jboss-logging.xml` e my `WEB-INF` dir for my app whit this configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<logging xmlns="urn:jboss:logging:6.0" xmlns:b="urn:jboss:bean-deployer:2.0" context="myApp">
   <define-context name="myApp" />

   <periodic-rotating-file-handler
         file-name="${jboss.server.log.dir}/myApp.log"
         name="WEBAPP" autoflush="true" append="true" suffix=".yyyy-MM-dd">
      <error-manager><only-once/></error-manager>
      <formatter>
         <pattern-formatter pattern="%d %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
      </formatter>
   </periodic-rotating-file-handler>

   <root-logger>
      <!-- Set the root logger priority via a system property, with a default value. -->
      <level name="${jboss.server.log.threshold:INFO}"/>
      <handlers>
         <handler-ref name="WEBAPP"/>
      </handlers>
   </root-logger>

</logging>
```

I get the following error when my app starts:

```
8:57:07,765 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Configured: name=Logging:REGISTRATION:myApp:Anonymous-0 state=Instantiated: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error configuring property: selector for Logging:REGISTRATION:myApp:Anonymous-0
          at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.ConfigureAction.dispatchSetProperty(ConfigureAction.java:112) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
          at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.ConfigureAction.setAttributes(ConfigureAction.java:85) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
          at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.ConfigureAction.installActionInternal(ConfigureAction.java:44) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
          at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
          at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
(...)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong arguments. setSelector for target org.jboss.logging.metadata.ClassLoaderRegistrationHelper@1a4eb51 expected=[org.jboss.logmanager.ClassLoaderLogContextSelector] actual=[org.jboss.logmanager.LogContextSelectorService]
          at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.handleErrors(ReflectionUtils.java:404) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
          at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:74) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
          at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectMethodInfoImpl.invoke(ReflectMethodInfoImpl.java:168) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
          at org.jboss.beans.info.plugins.DefaultPropertyInfo.set(DefaultPropertyInfo.java:143) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
          at org.jboss.beans.info.plugins.BeanInfoUtil.set(BeanInfoUtil.java:177) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
          at org.jboss.beans.info.plugins.AbstractBeanInfo.setProperty(AbstractBeanInfo.java:289) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
          at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.PropertyDispatchWrapper.execute(PropertyDispatchWrapper.java:114) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
          at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.ExecutionWrapper.execute(ExecutionWrapper.java:47) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
          at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchExecutionWrapper(KernelControllerContextAction.java:125) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
          at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.ConfigureAction.dispatchSetProperty(ConfigureAction.java:107) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
          ... 64 more
```

I will be grateful for any kind of info or direction on this subject, even one that represents using a complete different approach to logging in AS6. Although I feel I'm getting closer to the solution...  Thank you in advance.

---

<sub>The post [here](http://community.jboss.org/message/584720) is also mine</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug, it's reported here:
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBLOGGING-56

I tried the workaround that they mention, but couldn't get it to work either. Unfortunately, new logging framework in JBoss AS 6 seems to be very buggy and undocumented at this moment.

Comment: Thank you Robert, do you suggest an alternative? I was using log4J before, but thought it would be better if go with the application server...

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I'm not using AS 6 in production, so I just gave up on the logging issue for now, until they fix it and write some decent documentation. If I come across a solution, I'll post here.

Answer (score 5):

You can look here
http://lea-ka.blogspot.com/2011/09/assorted-facts-about-jboss-fact-3-how.html
and here
http://lea-ka.blogspot.com/2011/09/dynamically-changing-app-specific.html.

**01.12.2011. Update:**
Even better look here to see why you do not want to use it: http://lea-ka.blogspot.com/2011/12/assorted-facts-about-jboss-fact-4-per.html